# Standard user account for Windows 8.1 is created, but cannot login

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, user-accounts, windows-live

When creating users accounts I am signed in under my Microsoft Live account, this account is already part of the Administrators group. I can create the new **Standard User** account but when trying to log on to the account I get the following message

> The user profile service failed the sign-in

This is happening with every local account I create. I have tried deleting account and recreating with no resolution.

I am running a fully patched Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google searching "The user profile service failed the sign-in" found [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/38838-user-profile-service-failed-sign-fix-windows-8-a.html). Gives causes and tutorials, and has discussions with other users on alternate fixes.

> This tutorial will show you how to fix the "User Profile Service
>   service failed the sign-in. User Profile cannot be loaded." error when
>   trying to sign in to a user account in Windows 8, Windows RT, Windows
>   8.1, and Windows RT 8.1.

Edit: Adding additional options that might fix the problem.

1. Create a standard user account with a local login password. Then associate the Windows Live profile with that account. [Change](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/windows/3450080/how-change-user-accounts-on-windows-8/) the Microsoft Live associated with the Windows Login.
2. Dangerous solution suggested in Microsoft Forums [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c8c6390b-afcb-4782-881a-fb42e917a2ce/the-user-profile-service-service-failed-the-signin-user-profile-cannot-be-loaded?forum=w8itpronetworking) - [Repair Windows 8.1 Installation](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-repair-windows-8-1-installation/).
3. Check your Application logs for errors similar to the one detailed [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/7fb93109-218c-43d7-b29a-ceaffc598b58/user-profile-service-service-failed-the-logon-user-profile-cannot-be-loaded?forum=w7itprogeneral). The gist of the solution was:

> "I suggest you check the Advanced Security Settings for the
>   C:\Users\Default folder. Ensure you check the box "Replace all child
>   object permission with inheritable permissions from this object"."
>   Fixed this problem for me.  I am now able to logon with the newly
>   created accounts just fine. Hopefully this will help others as well!

Comment: I did try that but it did not fix my problem.

Comment: @Phil Murray Which option?

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no; please include pertinent information directly in your answer(s) and, if required, cite the website as a source.

Comment: @techie007 What if the information is too long to paraphrase, such as step by step instructions, or there are multiple possible answers to a complex question with no easily defined answer? Even the Microsoft Technet forums have no clearly defined answer to this problem.

Comment: If the link it points to dies, then your answer is of no use to anyone, that's the main reason.  The secondary reason is that we're not here to just be a site with links to other sites, we're here to provide answers.  The SE editor allows you to provide long answers.  If you have no clearly defined answer to provide, then you probably don't have a good answer worth providing - just suggestions.  Anyhow I appreciate that you lengthened your answer with some real info. :)

Answer (score 0):

While agreeing with the answer posted by Dennis Lu, I have to say this has something to do with the Default profile. Basically, the profile is created when the users logs in. If there is a problem during this procedure, data may not be copied from the default profile. It happens mostly due to file permissions. Therefore, you need to make sure the sub folders and files also inherit the same permissions from the default. This has to fix the problem. However, you also need to delete the current users. Also make sure you have the necessary permissions on disk (NTFS).

To delete the failed profiles, please use the **Advanced System Properties**. There is a tab labelled **Advanced**. While on that, click the **Settings** button under user profiles. This will list the existing profiles.